# API — JSON — PHP Как прописать путь к изображению?

Tags: php, html, json, api

Есть код

```
  <?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting('E_ALL');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/calendar?currency=RUB&origin=MOW&destination=AER&calendar_type=departure_date");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: "));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//var_dump($response);
$obj = json_decode($response);

echo '<table class="table table-hover">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Дата вылета</th>';
echo '<th>Стоимость</th>';
echo '<th>Авиакомпания</th>';
echo '<th>Актуально до</th>';
echo '<th>Дата возвращения</th>';
echo '<th>Номер рейса</th>';
echo '<tr> ';
$price = 0;
$num = 0;
$airline = array();
foreach ($obj->data as $key => $item) {
    $num++;
    $price += $item->price;
    if(isset($airline[$item->airline])){
        $airline[$item->airline]++;
    }else{
        $airline[$item->airline] = 1;
    }
 ;

   echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("$item->departure_at")) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $item->price . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . $item->airline . '</td>';    
    echo '<td>' . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("$item->expires_at"))  . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("$item->return_at")) . '</td>';    
    echo '<td>' . $item->flight_number . '</td>';

}  echo '</tr> '; echo '</table>';

?>
```

Мне нужно чтобы в коде заместо текстовой части вот этого кода

```
echo '<td>' . $item->airline . '</td>';
```

отображался логотип авиакомпании имеющий путь

```
pics.avs.io/100/40/***.png
```

где заместо звездочек было бы значение

```
 $item->airline
```

И еще нужно чтобы в конце каждой строчки таблицы была ссылка с названием "Поиск", ведущая на

```
bilety.avia-avia.ru/searches/new?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=***&depart_date=***&return_date=***&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true
```

где заместо звездочек вставлялись бы значения из таблицы. Вот что-то типо вот этого `http://avia-avia.ru/bilety_iz_moskvy/` Заранее спасибо с уважением.

Answer (score 1):

Замените эту строчку:

```
echo '<td>' . $item->airline . '</td>';
```

На:

```
echo '<td><img alt="" width="" height="" src="pics.avs.io/100/40/' . $item->airline . '.png"></td>';
```

Про поиск не со всем понятно, лучше уточните.

```
echo '<a href="bilety.avia-avia.ru/searches/new?origin_iata=MOW&destination_data=' . $item->flight_number . '&depart_date=' . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("$item->departure_at")) . '&return_date=' . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("$item->return_at")) . '&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true">Поиск</a>';
```

**А вообще конечно лучше почитать книги по HTML и PHP.**